# Google Sheet Special Pivot Table

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, flatten, google-sheets-formula

I don't find the solution to create the Output table from the Input one.

Could you please help me to find a solution to create this output table with pivot table or with a special formula which are not in my competence?

Here the link to the file where you will find the result that I would like (output table)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tEFlJisRlCy6RoJuGREuZV4hH_eUcIq6tZETy7RT_IM/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks a lot

Input

[image]

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX({{B3\0\1\2\3\4\"NA"\"[3]"\"[4]"}; B4:B13\IFNA(BYCOL({0\1\2\3\4\"NA"\"[3]"\"[4]"}; 
 LAMBDA(b; BYROW(B4:B13; LAMBDA(a; TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10); 1; 
 LAMBDA(x; FILTER(INDEX(x;;3); INDEX(x;;2)=b; INDEX(x;;1)=a))
 (SPLIT(FLATTEN(B4:B13&"​"&C4:G13&"​"&C3:G3); "​"))))))))})
```

[image]

### [step-by-step formula walkthrough](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jX77F9noxeN6qZQUx8iyRqJ6e_KjQyZgUOaIw5dIfvw/copy)

#### [why LAMBDA is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74393500/5632629)

Comment: Thanks a lot @player0, it works perfectly. It is impressive to do this kind of formula...Could you please explain me how this formula works, please ? Again a BIGggg thank you

Comment: @Vince sure, added step-by-step walkthrough

Comment: Thanks it was helpfull to have all explanations....but I will read again them during the incoming days, to try to understand definitively the final formula

Comment: @Vince maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74393500/5632629 if you scroll down on "why lambda?" part